# Why do I need to have installed certificates for https connections?

Tags: web-services, ssl, certificate

About communicating with an https resource, for example, a secured webservice, I have been reading from https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?4443,Consuming+web+services+under+https+in+Java, that in order to stablish a connection from Java "we must have installed the server certificate with which we seek communication. Such certificate contains the public key used to encrypt the information sent, only to be decoded by the server with its private key (read more here). So, at the time of consuming a service under https, we will need the server certificate in order to establish our communication"

Doubts:

1. As I understood, when you open a connection with an https resource, from a browser for example,  the server sents the certificate but you dont need to have it installed previously, or do I need to have it installed previously always in my machine(browser...)? why would I need it?

Thanks

Comment: You actually don't need a server certificate. [Anonymous Diffie Hellman cipher suites](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Diffie_Hellman#Diffie-Hellman_in_SSL.2FTLS) that do not need certificates are part of the SSL/TLS standards.  But AFAIK there are no out-of-the box SSL/TLS implementations that are configured to use them, as they're obviously not very secure, being trivially subject to MITM attacks.

Answer (score 0):

You normally have a list of CA you trust, and then you automatically trust any certificate presented by a server that was issued by one of these Certificate Authorities.

For higher security setup you could instead, out of band, get the other endpoint certificate and verify that it matches. You have however management problems as certificates do expire (CA certificates do expire too but more often in a 10-20 years timespan instead of individual certificates that are at most valid for 1 years, or even only 3 months for Let's Encrypt), and you would need to get hold of them with some trusted means.

Note that newer technologies, like DANE, allow a provider to insert in the DNS either the certificate (or its fingerprint) it uses or the certificate of the CA in order to signal to the client to make sure to use only connections to it that are done with those cryptographic materials (this fight against one of the flow of the current Web PKI in the sense that we trust by default too many CAs and any of them could deliver a certificate for any resources, hence the whole security is only the one of the weakest CA among all you have in your trust store, irrespective to which you are really using).

The DNS `CAA` record predates DANE and can also be used to signal which certificates are "allowed" for a given resource.

TLS provides multiple benefits, among which authentication and integrity. They are orthogonal but, contrary to intuition, authentication is more important (should come first) than integrity (no point to send content protected to a party you did not validate). Authentication in TLS is **typically** (it is not the only way to do it) done with X.509 certificates (often twice wrongfully named "SSL certificates"), either on one side, or both (it is kind of symetric in that aspect, each endpoint could authenticate the other, as needed).

Comment: Thanks, but as I understand,  the list of CA I trust are a list of CA certificates? Are different from the servers certificates? I think they do because the server certificate is a CA certificate but for a specific company and the CA certificate is not for any specific company, just the CA company itself

Comment: Technically, all certificates are the same: they carry a public key part, the name it covers, the name that signed it and some metadata such as dates. A server certificate is signed by another certificate, either an CA or an intermediate. You have a chain up to one "root" certificate, from one CA that has the properpty of being self signed showing the end of the chain. You have a list of such "root" certificates in your trust store (maintained by OS, or specific to each application, like a browser) and the software trusts them absolutely (aka: trust any certificate they signed)

Comment: There are various "types" of certificates: DV, OV, EV. Domain Validated ones are typically certificates where the name in it is just an hostname, the name of your server. Organization Validated are certificates where the name is the name of an organization, like "Acme, Inc." irrespective to which specific server you connect to. Extended Validation are a refinement over OV with stricter checks on issuance. CAs like Let's Encrypt deliver only DV certificates as those could be issued after only automated checks, which is impossible for OV/EV ones.